# what are the parameters of WndProc_OnSize(HWND hWnd, UINT state, int cx, int cy)

Tags: c, winapi

I mean

```
WndProc_OnCommand(HWND hWnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
```

can be rewrited like this

```
WndProc_OnCommand(hWnd, (int)LOWORD(wParam),(HWND)(lParam),(UINT)HIWORD(wParam));
```

But how to rewrite

```
 WndProc_OnSize(HWND hWnd, UINT state, int cx, int cy)
```

what will be here lparam,wparam?

Comment: These macros have already been written for you in windowsx.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx

wParam is state, while LOWORD(lParam) is cx, HIWORD lParam is cy.